# Unix sftp - mput command - transfer all files with a specific prefix

Tags: unix, sftp, filenames

I have bunch of files in a directory. But I would like to transfer to SFTP server only files starting with either `ABC` or `XYZ`. How do I filter these in my `mput` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your files all in current directory:

```
sftp user@server << EOF
cd /destination
$(for i in ABC* XYZ*; do echo "put $i"; done)
EOF
```

Output (example):

```
Connected to server.
sftp> cd /destination
sftp> put ABCfoo.txt
Uploading ABCfoo.txt to /destination/ABCfoo.txt
ABCfoo.txt                                                                100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00    
sftp> put XYZfoo.txt
Uploading XYZfoo.txt to /destination/XYZfoo.txt
XYZfoo.txt                                                                100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a file mask in [`sftp`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp) `put` command (or `mput` alias):

```
cd /destination/path
put ABC*
put XYZ*
```

---

Note that contrary to common command-line `ftp` client, in OpenSSH `sftp` the `put` itself can upload multiple files (and `mput` is just an undocumented alias to `put`).